# What is the largest aircraft (by max takeoff weight) in which all engines are in the tail?

Tags: aircraft-design, weight-and-balance, weight

The largest one I'm aware of is the [Il-62](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-62), with a whopping 4 turbofans at its tail. Max takeoff weight is 165 tons.

I actually don't care how many engines there are, as long as **all** are at the tail. I don't care what kind either, turbofans, turbojets, anything. Don't care if it's military or civilian.

**Edit:** Airbreathing engines only. The space shuttle and buran don't go above 109 tons anyway, but the criteria here is max takeoff weight and those rockets "take off" far too differently than airplanes.

I googled this of course, but predictably these kinds of "what's the biggest" questions with specific conditions attached are not well-known. I'm hoping someone will know of an example bigger than 165 tons.

The reason I ask is because I'm curious just how much engine weight can be put at the tail and still have a conventionally-shaped aircraft. I'm a little surprised at the Il-62, actually. Sooner or later, to keep the center of mass ahead of the center of drag, the wings have to move more and more back until suddenly you have a canard config where the wings almost operate like a delta where the ailerons are also elevons and maybe even flaps.

Comment: Well... Not quite an aircraft (it's ekranoplan) and not quite having its engines at the tail (its engine are at the nose), but this is too good to not mention: the Lun class ekranoplan - 8 turbojets, all in the very front. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lun-class_ekranoplan

Comment: How about the [Saturn V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V)? That certainly had all the engines in the tail... Failing that, the Space Shuttle is at  least more aircrafty.

Comment: @DanieleProcida The shuttle is indeed more aircrafty, but it never had its engines running when flying as an aircraft.

Comment: There was a Buran test bed with 4 jet engines in the tail (OK-GLI, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OK-GLI), but MTOW in that configuration is below 100 tons.

Comment: What about blended wing body planes with the engines at the rear? Or are you only interested in tubes with wings?

Comment: @Owen Those are fine but let's keep it to aircraft that have actually flown without crashing. I'm not aware of any flying wing, actually flying, that goes above 165 tons.

Comment: @DeepSpace That goes airborne and breathes air so I consider it an aircraft. Ground effect doesn't disqualify it. Some early flights, I think even the Wright flier, were also pretty low and might've used ground effect, but that doesn't disqualify a flight. It's still lift after all.

Comment: @DanieleProcida Space shuttle orbiter is not more than 30 tons. I think I'm gonna edit the OP to only include airbreathing engines anyway. When the criteria is max takeoffweight, rockets "take off" very differently from planes anyway.

Comment: `space shuttle and buran don't go above 30 tons` - Both maxed over 100 tonnes. Heck, the Shuttle could carry almost 30 tons to orbit.

Comment: @HephaestusAetnaean Darn, so much for my memory. Wikipedia says the shuttle's max takeoff weight is 109 tons. Astronautix.com says Buran's gross mass is 105 tons. Pretty hefty stuff.

Comment: I was thinking B-2 spirit but upon closer inspection the engines are mid wing, not at the rear. MTOW is 188 tons.

Answer (score 6):

I think you've got it. Surprising to see how much larger it was than the VC.10.

There was a planned development of the VC-10 that used the VC-10 wing and tailplanes with a new double-deck fuselage. This [VC-10 Superb](http://www.vc10.net/History/doubledeck_super_vc10.html) (DB.265) had a planned MTOW of 174 tons.

Comment: Not _that_ much larger (165 tonnes, versus 151.9 for the VC10-1101).

Answer (score 0):

The B-1B has its engines behind the wing (at least in "wing-forward" configuration,) and a MTOW of 477,000 pounds, according to Boeing.

Comment: If B-1B counts, then the heavier Tu-160 would count too (275 tons/606,000 lb). But not really, they both have 'under wing' sort of configuration.